# Displaying multiple Views in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am passing multiple models to my view using dynamic models but now I don't know how to Display the models.

How do I do this with dynamic models?

Feel free to ask if you lack Information.

Comment: What exactly do you want to display from your model? and can you post your model code if possible please

Comment: I am displaying Buttons with the names of the teachers on it. Teachers is a list<teacher>. The teacher model consist of an int Id, string Name and int Age.

Comment: What do you mean _dynamic models_?

Comment: I use radiobuttons and I need to work with the list later on. If I do it with foreach and submit it, the list will be empty

Comment: @Izzy, It needs to be `IList<Teachers>` to work with a `for` loop.

Comment: @StephenMuecke In my controller I am using System.dynamics and create a ExpandoObject. If you give me a Minute I'll edit my post.

Comment: try to create an attribute listteachers in the model. then call this list in a foreach or for loop using model.listTeachers

Comment: Do not use `dynamic`. Create a view model with 2 collection properties, one for `List<Teacher>` and one for `List<student>`. Bot your view make no sense. You have a form but nothing can be edited. You just generating a whole lot of pointless html. And you form cannot possibly bind to a model anyway. What is it that you trying to do?

Comment: Check out this link for complete knowledge on Multiple Models in one View 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/multiple-models-in-single-view-in-mvc/

Comment: @REDEVI_  I was exactly using this side to look up passing multiple models to one view. It is also the site were I found dynamic. My Problem is that he always displays his data with foreach.

Comment: whats the problem with foreach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your Model like this

```
public class ExpandoObject
{
  public List<Teacher> ListTeachers {get; set;}
   public List<Student> ListStudent { get; set;}
}
```

Then your action

```
public ActionResult DisplayModel()
        {
            ExpandoObject yourModel = new ExpandoObject();
            List<Teacher> listofteachers = dbh.GetTeachers();
            List<student> listofstudents = dbh.Students();

            mymodels.ListTeachers = listofteachers;
            mymodels.ListStudents = listofstudents;

            return View("ModelView", yourModel );
        }
```

and your view should be like this

```
    @model ExpandoObject
    <head>
        <link href="~/Content/test.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("DisplayModel", "Home"))
        {
            <table>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListTeachers.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <tr class="donatenow">
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].ID)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Name)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Age)
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio" id="@i" name="amount" onclick="javascript: this.form.submit();" />
                            <label for="@i">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ListTeachers[i].Name)</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }

            </table>

 <table>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListStudents.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <tr class="donatenow">
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].ID)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Name)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Age)
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio" id="@i" name="amount" onclick="javascript: this.form.submit();" />
                            <label for="@i">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ListStudents[i].Name)</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }

            </table>
        }
    </body>
```

And the best way to diplay your Model is using  a  partial view for each collection .

Comment: You have to Change "@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Name)" to "@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.listofteachers[i].Name)"

Comment: Yes Thanks. there are some improvement in the razor code. But I focused on Models design.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to my demo!";
        dynamic mymodel = new ExpandoObject();
        mymodel.Teachers = GetTeachers();
        mymodel.Students = GetStudents();
        return View(mymodel);
    }
```

In Your View

```
@using YourProjNameSpace;
@model dynamic
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>

<p><b>Teacher List</b></p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (Teacher teacher in Model.Teachers)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@teacher.TeacherId</td>
            <td>@teacher.Code</td>
            <td>@teacher.Name</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

<p><b>Student List</b></p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Enrollment No</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (Student student in Model.Students)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@student.StudentId</td>
            <td>@student.Code</td>
            <td>@student.Name</td>
            <td>@student.EnrollmentNo</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```